# ¿Es posible usar async en peticiones http FETCH en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy implementado un sistema web pero las peticiones http con fetch en JavaScript hacen lenta la conexión entonces estuve pensando, ¿Sera posible implementar peticiones asíncronas sucesivas?.
Me estoy basando en dart y el paquete http para hacer peticiones asíncronas

```
Future pricesIOT() async {
await http
    .post(
        Uri.parse("https://"))
    .then((data) async { //code });
```

Mi idea es implementar algo similar pero es JavaScript de este modo estaría mejorando el rendimiento de mi sistema,
**será posible?**

Comment: Si haces peticiones en serie (_que no dependen entre si_) va a demorar más que se las hicieras a todas juntas en paralelo. Lectura recomendada [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 3):

Sí, se puede usar async. Eso no te va a mejorar la performance porque usar Promise.then o await solo difiere en la sintaxis, pero internamente hace lo mismo.

En vez de

```js
await http
    .post(
        Uri.parse("https://"))
    .then((data) async { //code });
```

se puede hacer

```js
var request = await http.post(Uri.parse("https://"))
var data = request.text();  // o request.json() o lo que estés usando
// etc...
```